# Autoplay of HTML 5 Video element

Tags: html5-video, razor-pages

I've  2 html 5 vidoes elmenets within a razor page, the 1st gets auto played when the page is rendered even without using the autoplay attribute however the 2nd one doesn't.

Note: the 2nd video element is set to render speicfic duration of the video file using src= "#t=start,end"

Any idea about how can overcome this ?

I can provide the html snnipet if needed.

I tried to set the autoplay attribue on the 2nd video but that didn't make the deal.